# Largest maxRequestLength I can have in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.0

I have a very simple file upload in place. But I would like to increase this to a much higher transfer such as 700Mb+. Its okay transferring 20Mb files but that ins't fulfilling my needs. So my question is:
How can I have a large 700Mb+ request?

My current web config looks like this:

```
configuration
    system.web
      compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" 
      customErrors mode="Off"
      httpRuntime executionTimeout="120000000"
       maxRequestLength="999999999999999"
       useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false"
       minFreeThreads="8"
       minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4"
       appRequestQueueLimit="100"
       system.web
configuration
```

My upload looks like this:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"       Inherits="_Default" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 

<script runat="server">

  protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
  String savePath = Server.MapPath(".\\");

    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
      String fileName = FileUpload1.FileName;

      savePath += fileName;

      FileUpload1.SaveAs(savePath);

      UploadStatusLabel.Text = "Your file was saved as " + fileName;
    }
    else
     {      
      UploadStatusLabel.Text = "You did not specify a file to upload.";
    }

  }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>FileUpload Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
   <h4>Select a file to upload:</h4>

   <asp:FileUpload id="FileUpload1"                 
       runat="server">
   </asp:FileUpload>

   <br /><br />

   <asp:Button id="UploadButton" 
       Text="Upload file"
       OnClick="UploadButton_Click"
       runat="server">
   </asp:Button>    

   <hr />

   <asp:Label id="UploadStatusLabel"
       runat="server">
   </asp:Label>        
</div>
</form>
```

**EDIT:**

The response I get when uploading is:
404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: What happens when you try uploading a 700MB file?

Comment: @mbeckish - I have included my error output as an edit.

Comment: Just in case `MaxRequestLength` is an int32, try setting it to `2147483647` instead of something way to large. Should be big enough :) Although if you are going to be sending files that large I would recommend you to use another protocol instead, maybe FTP? (file transfer protocol..)

Comment: @flindeberg - I know I can use FTP for this but I would rather learn how to do it this way. I have considered a java applet too. Thanks for the quick response though and I will try your suggestion.